# Best way to store JSON where SQL seems unnecessary

Tags: mysql, sql, angularjs, json

I've created an angularjs webapp which allows you to interact with a large JSON object to change an on screen configuration. For example, click a button and...

```
{'open': true, 'color': 'red', 'beef': 'jerky'}
```

changes to

```
{'open': true, 'color': 'blue', 'beef': 'cake'}
```

... and the changes you've made are reflected in a visible configuration on screen.

I've made a backend login which allows people to create an account linked to their email with all their data in an mySQL database.

The goal is that a user would create a configuration of the JSON object, 'save' it and then be able to access it later. With angularjs I presumably could parse all this JSON into a gigantic table, but...

- I do not need to query the JSON with SQL ever (the data is only used by the front-end code as one big block)
- I may change how the JSON is structured/how many options are within it over time, I'm imagining that would make a gigantic custom table an extra thing to have to change

Would it be better for me to simply store that big block of JSON as a string in one column? Is this bad practice? Will I theoretically have a limit on the stringlength allowed in one table cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic configuration JSON objects, it is highly recommended that you parse it and store it as a string.

There is of course a maximum length for the string you can store in one cell, however it is extremely large (any huge JSON object would fit).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply @David H. , so you're agreeing that turning it into one string and storing it in a single cell is acceptable for this purpose?

Comment: Awesome, let the stringification begin!

Answer (score 1):

Trying to help...

There are [several NoSQL database types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Types_and_examples_of_NoSQL_databases) you can use. I'd recommend you to use the Document Store database. I believe the most used Document Store database is [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)

The example below stores JSON data into MongoDB.

[MongoDB and NodeJS tutorial](http://blog.modulus.io/mongodb-tutorial)

```
//lets require/import the mongodb native drivers.
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

//We need to work with "MongoClient" interface in order to connect to a mongodb server.
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
    console.log('Connection established to', url);

    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('users');

    //Create some users
    var user1 = {name: 'modulus admin', age: 42, roles: ['admin', 'moderator', 'user']};
    var user2 = {name: 'modulus user', age: 22, roles: ['user']};
    var user3 = {name: 'modulus super admin', age: 92, roles: ['super-admin', 'admin', 'moderator', 'user']};

    // Insert some users
    collection.insert([user1, user2, user3], function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Inserted %d documents into the "users" collection. The documents inserted with "_id" are:', result.length, result);
      }
      //Close connection
      db.close();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Cheers @valdek , because I've already got a mySQL database for my users (and partially because I'm very much still getting my head around SQL) I feel like adding an additional form of database (noSQL) might complicate things too much for my needs here.I did previously look into noSQL before asking this- and I appreciate the advice. Maybe if this doesn't work I'll try it your way. Thanks again.